# ExpressionEngine how long channel entries published

Tags: expressionengine, channel

I am currenlty building blog with expressionengine. i want to display how long the entries have published.
How can i get how long hours/day ago channel entries published?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem,

in my template, i allow PHP

then i add this code that i found from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/time-ago-function/

but don't use function, i don't know but it gives me error. just straight to the main
like this:

```
<?php
$time = strtotime("{entry_date format="%d %F %Y"}");
   $periods = array("Second", "Minute", "Hour", "Day", "Week", "Month", "Year", "Decade");
   $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

   $now = time();

       $difference     = $now - $time;
       $tense         = "ago";

   for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
       $difference /= $lengths[$j];
   }

   $difference = round($difference);

   if($difference != 1) {
       $periods[$j].= "s";
   }

   echo "$difference $periods[$j] Ago";

?>
```

may help another that having the same problem as i am